# no matching constructor for initialization of cccolor4f in cocos2d-x

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x

I am creating a game like bounce ball using cocos2d-x and box2d. I want to draw a circle and fill with color. But i am getting the following error.

"no matching constructor for initialization of cccolor4f"

I am using the following code to draw a circle.

```
CCDrawNode *drawnode = CCDrawNode::create();
drawnode->drawDot(ccp(15,CCDirector::sharedDirector()
->getVisibleSize().height/2),50,ccColor4F(255,255,255,255));

this->addChild(drawnode);
```

Please advice.

Comment: which cocos2d-x version you are using ??

Comment: This might help >  http://ladywendy.com/lab/cocos2d-x/32.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might give it this way .

```
ccColor4F MyColor = {255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f}; 
CCDrawNode *drawnode = CCDrawNode::create();
drawnode->drawDot(ccp(15,CCDirector::sharedDirector()
->getVisibleSize().height/2),50,MyColor);

this->addChild(drawnode);
```